# Restore running Async Task in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm looking for a **complete** example of an activity which uses async task and implements a way to refer to a running async task after the activity is paused (onPause).
I searched the web for an example which I could use but didn't find a complete one, only code fragments.

I'm using async task to ping servers in my app, but a way to save a reference to running async tasks is missing so after onPause, the running tasks get lost.

thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Could you please paste the code you have tried?

Comment: hi, i haven't tried a specific solution. You can find my code [here](http://pastebin.com/VvEMhunw) I haven't overwritten anything like onSavedInstance or onRestoreInstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [Commonsware blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html).  He has an example of an asynctask working across orientation changes.

Comment: This example is very useful, but what about multiple async tasks between instances?

Comment: Thanks for the link, the information provided helped me to solve my problem :) I'm saving my async tasks in a list which is restored after orientation change. By iterating over the list I'm attaching every task.